# Deadlocks when running NServicebus service causes corrupt connection

Tags: nhibernate, deadlock, nservicebus

We're running NServiceBus for a web application to handle situations where the user do "batch like" actions. Like fire a command that affects 1000 entities..

It works well, but during moderate load we get some deadlocks, this isn't a problem, just retry the message.. right? :)

The problem occurs when the next message arrives and tries to open a connection. The connection is then "corrupt".

We get the following error:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): New request is not allowed to start because it should come with valid transaction descriptor

I've searched the web and I think our problem is a reported [NH "bug"](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3023):

A workaround should be to disable connection pooling. But I don't like that, since performce will degrade..

We're running NServiceBus 2.6, NHibernate 3.3.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Can a upgrade of NServiceBus help?

Comment: This sounds very similar to an issue we're having. We haven't solved it yet, and are currently limping along with pooling off. What's your setup regarding MSDTC?

Comment: We have 2 web boxes (hardware load balanced, ip-sticky) and a failover sql server cluster with the MS DTC Server.

Comment: We've now disabled connection pooling and the problem doesn't occur anymore.

Comment: I think you already have way more info than what I can help you with from the linked questions, but I just wanted to throw in that in our case, the problem is apparently worsened by bad DTC performance leading to SQL timeouts. These seem to be mitigated by using remote DTC instead of local DTC as explained in this article: http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/msdnmirror/archive/2010/05/11/resolving-dtc-related-waits-and-tuning-scalability-of-dtc.aspx

Comment: Ok! Thanks, I'll verify if that is related to our env. we have experienced some SQL timeouts that "shouldn't" be there

Comment: We are experiencing this exact issue.  Any further advice besides disabling connection pooling?  Any serious ill-effects from disabling connection pooling?

Comment: The only thing that helps is disabling cp. But it works well.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve seen this in the past, if your design warrants, try breaking the transaction into two, if you flow the message transaction all the way to your database operations, any failures will have a cascading effect and it will impact (ideally it shouldn’t) any subsequent messages as well.

Comment: To add a bit more clarity, what I meant was to use a nested transaction. Database transaction should not have an effect on the overall message transaction.

Comment: We break everything into small short transactions using a saga. But when deadlock still occurs, we get the error when connection pooling is on.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating the 1000 entities in the command could you publishing an event to say that the command has been completed and then have several subscribers acting on this event to update effect entities. It sounds to me that a command that updates a 1000 entities should be split into a number of smaller commands. Take a look a the sagas to see how you can handle long running business process. For example, you might have something like, process started, step 1 completed, step 2 completed , process completed etc...

Comment: That is what we do. When e.g. the user issues a command that affects 1000 entities we split the command into one per "entity". And it's handled by a saga.

Comment: But when one of the transactions get deadlocked, the connection returned to the connection pool is corrupt and when the service retries the message it gets the corrupt connection, and we get the transaction error message for all new messages..